# How to release flutter app apk if I using laravel api as backend

Tags: laravel, flutter

I have a problem on release a flutter application(with Laravel API) APK. It is an e-commerce application, and the application is in two platforms, which are web-based for vendors and mobile-based for customers. I have done deploy websites for vendors. I have added the website URL to the flutter API file and then run the command to release the flutter APK. The application does not get the data from my database. How to fix this？

My website URL is http://creamee.epizy.com/

Below is my source code of retrieving the data by using LARAVEL API

```
fetchVendor() async {
var url = "http://creamee.epizy.com/api/vendors";
var response = await http.get(url);
// print(response.body);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  List<dynamic> items = json.decode(response.body)['data'];
  setState(() {
    vendors = items.map((vendor) => Vendor.fromJson(vendor)).toList();

    // isLoading = false;
  });
} else {
  setState(() {
    vendors = [];
  });
  // isLoading = false;
}
```

}

Comment: does everything work in debug apk ?

Comment: Is everything okay with debugging apk? could you add code of APIs file?

Comment: @DaliHamza Yes, everything work.

Comment: @YohanMalshika yes, all the data and function perform well when debugging apk.